# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SECURITY_JPA_REACTIVE | Quarkus

Tags: security, hash, password-hash, quarkus-reactive, quarkus-jpa

I have built an Item API that performs CRUD function, generates an otp token now I want to hash password using

> BcryptUtil.bcryptHash(password)

but when I add the quarkus-security-jpa-reactive dependency

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-security-jpa-reactive</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file and tried to reload my project it throws the Exception when I have not even written any code to make use of the dependency

> Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
> [error]: Build step io.quarkus.security.jpa.reactive.deployment.QuarkusSecurityJpaReactiveProcessor#feature threw an exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SECURITY_JPA_REACTIVE
> at io.quarkus.security.jpa.reactive.deployment.QuarkusSecurityJpaReactiveProcessor.feature(QuarkusSecurityJpaReactiveProcessor.java:60)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

How can I resolve this issue.